# How to instantiate fragment class using class name instead of index

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have two fragment class named `SessionTab` and `BillingTab`and i am trying to create instance of those class using

```
SessionTab sessionTab = (SessionTab) getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(1);
```

but sometimes index for those classes are reversed and then it causes `ClassCastException`

How can i get instance of those fragment class by passing class name instead of index or any way to make sure that index of those class stays the same everytime so it doesn't cause `ClassCastException`

Comment: post rest of your code if you still need help.

Answer (score 6):

Use one of this methods : `findFragmentById()` and `findFragmentByTag()` methods.

Reference : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#findFragmentById(int)

Update :

`ClassCastException` is invoked when you are not casting the appropriate classes to one another. In your case, Your `FragmentManager` is returning different fragment than `SessionTab`, so the exception is thrown.

If you use `findFragmentById()` or `findFragmentByTag()` , then it will return the fragment exactly what you want, and exception will not be thrown.

Answer (score 5):

Define a 'tag' for the Fragment while adding it like

```
 getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(new Fragment(),"your_tag");
```

And while referencing it use

```
getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("your_tag");
```

In most cases, you would like to use `YourFragment.class.getSimpleName()` as your tag.

Comment: I am not sure how to implement it. I am not able to instantiate my class using this

Comment: I think this is the best and cleanest way of doing it.
@AkashKumar where are you stuck at?

Comment: @ZorawarSachdev `YourFragment.class.getSimpleName()` gave fragments parent activity class name not current fragment class name

Answer (score 3):

First of all, if you should understand that instance for any Fragment you can take from Java class api. Like below:

```
Class<?> class = Class.forName("example.package.BillingFragment");
Constructor<?> cons = class.getConstructor(BillingFragment.class);
BillingFragment object = (BillingFragment) cons.newInstance();
```

Code example show, how get Instance from any class in Java. But you talking a little bit other things. If I understand correct, you want to get Fragment from FragmentManager.

You can do it, in case if you already defined Fragment before! For example, you have base application flow, and then you want added Fragment. You can check FragmentManager if there are Fragments in stack. But in case of empty stack, you should manually add them:

```
String billingFragmentTag = BillingFragment.class.getSimpleName();

......

if (getFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(billingFragmentTag) == null) {
  BillingFragment fragment = new BillingFragment();
  String billingFragmentTag = BillingFragment.class.getSimpleName();

  FragmentTransaction fragTrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
           fragTrans.add(fragment, billingFragmentTag).commit();
}

......
```

So after this, you can check if there your Fragment in stack and hook this active instance. This is correct and standard flow for using Fragments.

```
......

if (getFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(billingFragmentTag) != null) {
  BillingFragment fragment = getFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(billingFragmentTag);
  String billingFragmentTag = BillingFragment.class.getSimpleName();

  FragmentTransaction fragTrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
           fragTrans.add(fragment, billingFragmentTag).commit();
}

....
```

Welcome!

Comment: why dont you just do
BillingFragment object = new BillingFragment();